# Count if two consecutive cells match a specific criteria

Tags: google-sheets, countif

[Take this spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rggAW.png)

I am trying to count the number of times blue is followed by green in the range. You can see I tried using the formula

```
=countif(A1:A20,B1:B2)
```

This did not work as it should return 3, but is only counting the number of times blue appears. How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=countifs(A1:A19,B1,A2:A20,B2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!